# Iterating over a java hashmap in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am new to Clojure and I am trying to iterate over a java hashmap in Clojure.
I have the following simple hashmap `{message=[hello, world]}`.
I am writing the following clojure program to iterate over it.

Clojure code:

```
(defn Print [m]
    (doseq [[k v] m]
         (prn k)
         (doseq [[p q] v]
               (prn p)
               (prn q))))
```

Java code:

```
package com.example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import clojure.java.api.Clojure;
import clojure.lang.IFn;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
        require.invoke(Clojure.read("com.example.core"));
        IFn Print = Clojure.var("com.example.core", "Print");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("world");
        map.put("message", list);
        Print.invoke(map);
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
"message" 
\h
\e
\w
\o
```

I am trying to get the output:
message hello world

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the clojure code I am also writing-  (defn -main [m]
                                                                 (Print m))

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
(doseq [[p q] v]
  (prn p)
  (prn q))
```

you are iterating over a list, assigning the first element of each element to `p`, the second to `q`.  Since you have a list of strings there, you print the first two characters of each.

You seem to want:

```
(doseq [s v]
  (prn s))
```

By the way, Clojure uses lower case names: the function should be named `print`, although you should try to come up with a better name, since that name already exists in Clojure core and would be shadowed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will pay attention to the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this... map function can be used to iterate a collection
besides doses... map, loop/recur and user defined recursive function with (first, empty?, rest) can also be used to achieve same.

```
(def my-map {"message" '("hello" "world")}) 
(map (fn[[k v]] (prn k v))  my-map)
```